# Is it appropriate to flag another comment "no longer needed" after writing a similar, more precise one?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, comment-flags

I just came across a question on Stack Overflow, and asked the OP to enhance his problem statement. Another person did the same in parallel, ending up with:

[image: screenshot]

Now, I am simply wondering: is it appropriate/legitimate for me to flag that *other* comment for "no longer needed", as there is now a "better" comment addressing the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, flagging the comment is appropriate but I'd go with a custom comment in this case, instead of the standard option "No longer needed". The reason is that the ♦ moderator handling the flag will see the *post* and the *flagged comment* in the queue, but **not** your own comment. Some (on busy sites like Stack Overflow, almost all) flags are handled from the queue, and you risk your flag being declined because of this; all the moderator will see is a subpar-quality post and a justified comment.

A custom message "no longer needed, I've posted an improved version of this comment" isn't that much work to type and 100% clear to the moderator. They'll visit the post, notice that you're right and delete the flagged comment.